# C++ object needs to update its vector and map of shared pointers to other objects

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, boost-thread, stdmap

I have `FooManager` class with a public member `std::map<size_t, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> fmap;` for keeping track of `Foo` instances. There is an additional `farray` public member of `FooManager` which is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>`. The `Foo` instances are added as,

```
FooManager fooman;
int total_foos = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < total_foos; ++i) {
    auto ff = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo_data, i);  // calls Foo constructor
    fooman.farray[i] = ff;
    fooman.fmap.emplace(ff->GetID(), ff);  // note that ff.id != index i
}
```

Each `Foo` instance runs a [`boost::thread`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread.html) process, and I'm using `FooManager` to keep track -- initially I found this approach more straightforward than a [`boost::thread::group`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup), but I could be mistaken.

At a barrier, where each `Foo` instance is waiting for `fooman` to do a computation that decides which `Foo` instances continue and which don't, I have a result `foo_continues` (a `std::vector<int>`) that corresponds to the indices of `fooman.farray`. If, for example, `foo_continues[3]=2` and `foo_continues[7]=0`, I need the `Foo` instance corresponding to index 7 to be deleted, and that of index 3 to continue *with two entries* being track in `fooman`. Importantly, I need the containers `fooman.farray` and `fooman.fmap` to update accordingly. How can this be done in a `FooManager::CommputeContinues` method?

And if you have an alternative approach than to keeping both `fooman.farray` and `fooman.fmap`, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Also use a [`condition_variable`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/synchronization/conditions.html) and signal the thread directly instead of this strange extra vector.

Comment: What does "with two entries" being tracked in `fooman`" mean?  Do you create a new `shared_ptr`, or do you have two entries in `farray` with one entry in `fmap`?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need both a `map` and a `vector` in the first place. What about just signaling the threads that should stop, then after passing the barrier you join those threads and remove them from the map.

Comment: Each `Foo` instance runs a thread that calls a function `func`. I would like the logic within `func` to be able to reference the `Foo` instance that called it. I accomplish this by getting the `boost::thread::id` within `func`, which is hashed to give a `size_t` value. This `size_t` value is the key for the corresponding shared_ptr `Foo`in `fmap`. Thus, from within `func`, I can ask `foomap` which `Foo` is in charge of the thread. This is why I have `fmap`.

Comment: @super what would that look like?

Comment: *"Each `Foo` instance runs a thread that calls a function `func`. I would like the logic within `func` to be able to reference the `Foo` instance that called it."* Why not just have `Foo` pass its `this` pointer down to `func` as a parameter? Or equivalently, make `func` a member of `Foo`?

Comment: If you do what Igor suggested, then you can add a `bool terminate_thread` in `Foo` to signal the thread that it should terminate. Check the bool after threads pass the barrier, terminate if set. Remove all `Foo` that terminated.